# Arduino LED blinking issue

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, led

So I have a Bluetooth module that I've created some code for, so that when i push button 1 it turns on the led, when i push 2 it turns off the led, and 3 is supposed to make the led continuously blink. Everything works perfectly fine, except that when i push 3 the led blinks once then stops. What can i do to the code to make it blink continuously until i either hit button 1 or 2 again?

```
char LED = 0;

void setup() {
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600); // Opens Serial port 
}

void loop() {
    if (Serial.available()> 0){
        LED = Serial.read();
        Serial.print(LED);

        if (LED == '1') 
            digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
        if (LED == '0') 
            digitalWrite(13, LOW);
        if (LED == '3') {
            digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
            delay(1000);
            digitalWrite(13, LOW);
            delay(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it looks like you're missing a brace on the third if?

Comment: Tried that but it still only blinks once.

Comment: silly question but is LED actually 3 every time in that loop, or is there a default response of 0 that is being read when there is nothing being sent?

Comment: not really sure wucha mean, i have the button on my android device set to when i push the blinking led switch it sends a 3 to the serial monitor. is that what your talking about?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change main loop to:

```
void loop() {
    if (Serial.available()> 0){
        LED = Serial.read();
        Serial.print(LED);
    }

    if (LED == '3') {
        digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
        delay(1000);
        digitalWrite(13, LOW);
        delay(1000);
    }
    else if (LED == '1') 
        digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    else if (LED == '0') 
        digitalWrite(13, LOW);
}
```

In this case `LED == '3'` will be work on every loop iteration, even if `Serial` is not contain any data

Comment: Eyy that got it working! thanks so much, been fiddling with the code for two days now.

Answer (score 0):

You put the blinking code into the `if (Serial.available()> 0)` block, which means that it's only run when you send a `'3'`. You would need to keep sending `'3'` to keep the LED blinking.

Sergey gave you a working solution, but that code unnecessarily keeps setting the LED on or off, and the code is unresponsive while the LED is blinking because of the use of `delay`.

To fix those problems you need to use a variable to keep a state (In Sergey's code that role took your existing `LED` variable) and use `millis()` instead of `delay()` for blinking, like in the BlinkWithoutDelay builtin Arduino IDE example.

```
char LED = 0;
enum {
    NONE,
    BLINKING,
} state = NONE;

void setup() {
    pinMode(BUILTIN_LED, OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600); // Opens Serial port 
}

void loop() {
    if (Serial.available() > 0){
        LED = Serial.read();
        Serial.print(LED);

        switch (LED) {
            case '1':
                 state = NONE;
                 digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED, HIGH);
                 break;
            case '2':
                 state = NONE;
                 digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED, LOW);
                 break;
            case '3':
                 state = BLINKING;
                 break;
        }
    }
    switch (state) {
        case NONE: break;
        case BLINKING:
            static unsigned long last_blink = 0;
            if (millis() - last_blink > 1000)
            {
                digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED, !digitalRead(BUILTIN_LED));
                last_blink = millis();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```